# How to display content in random order?

Tags: php, mysqli

With code below I am displaying questions retrieved from database:

```
    $qandaquery = "SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent
                    FROM Question q
                    WHERE SessionId = ?
                    GROUP BY q.QuestionId
                    ORDER BY q.QuestionId";

    $qandaqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($qandaquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $qandaqrystmt->bind_param("i",$session);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $qandaqrystmt->execute(); 
    $qandaqrystmt->bind_result($qandaQuestionId,$qandaQuestionNo,$qandaQuestionContent);

    $arrQuestionId = array();
    $arrQuestionNo = array();
    $arrQuestionContent = array();


    while ($qandaqrystmt->fetch()) {
    $arrQuestionId[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionId;
    $arrQuestionNo[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionNo;
    $arrQuestionContent[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionContent;

  }

    $qandaqrystmt->close();


foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class='lt-container'>
<p><strong>QUESTION <span id="quesnum"></span>:</strong></p>
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>
</div>


<?php

}

?>
```

Now WHERE it says `QUESTION`:

`<p><strong>QUESTION # <?php echo $q; ?> :</strong></p>
<?php
$q++;
?>`

I want that to stay the same place

But where it displays the question details:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>
```

I want it to display the questions in RANDOM order. So for example if I have 3 questions as below:

```
QUESTION 1:

1. What is 2+2?

QUESTION 2:

2. What is 3+3?

QUESTION 3:

3. What is 4+4?
```

It could be displayed in this order as an example:

```
QUESTION 1:

2. What is 3+3?

QUESTION 2:

3. What is 4+4?

QUESTION 3:

1. What is 2+2?
```

Comment: learn how to [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ORDER BY q.QuestionId` use `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: Just one question with this method, I want to add some check boxes with each question, theses checkboxes will be answers, the answers are in the query anyway, correct and incorrect answers, If I use your method, will those checkbox answers belong with those questions when they go random? Does that make sense?

Comment: With what I have given you, the rows will be randomized together.  I.e. all columns will match for the given row, it's just that the rows will be shuffled

Answer (score 0):

The `shuffle()` function randomizes the order of the elements in the array. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Example

```
<?php
$my_array = array("a" => "Dog", "b" => "Cat", "c" => "Horse");

shuffle($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>

rray ( [0] => Cat [1] => Horse [2] => Dog )
```

Comment: So looking at it, do I need to just shuffle `$arrQuestionId` in my code

Answer (score 0):

How about  mysql rand() function e.g

```
$qandaquery = "SELECT rand() as pos, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent
                    FROM Question q
                    WHERE SessionId = ?
                    GROUP BY q.QuestionId
                    order by pos";
```